# Joomla 2.5 add parent alias as body class

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

The code changed since Joomla 1.5, here's my try :

In the head

```
<?php $parent = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getParent(); ?>
```

On the body tag

```
<body class="<?php echo $parent->alias; ?>">
```

Any idea of what's wrong...? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found your post then found this, which I think answers it perfectly, well at least it did for me

http://www.joomla4web.com/blog/finding-the-top-menu.html

```
 $menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
$active = $menu->getActive();
$top = $active ? $menu->getItem($active->tree[0]) : null;
echo $top->alias;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using:

```
<?php
$menu =& JSite::getMenu();
$active = $menu->getActive();
$class = extractpath($active->route);
function extractpath($string){
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+/',$string,$m);
return $m[0];
}

?>
<body<?php if ($class) echo ' class="' . $class . '"'; ?>>
```